# Windows 11 login impossibile via RDP e SMB

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, smb

I've got a Windows 11 that rejects all RDP and SMB logins.
I use a Microsoft account and pc is not domain joined.
It logs the following event.

```
Log Name:      
Security Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 
Date:          09/07/2022 16:26:41 
Event ID:      4625 
Task Category: Logon 
Level:         
Information Keywords:      
Audit Failure User:          N/A 
Computer:      *******
Description: An account failed to log on.  
Subject:    
Security ID:        NULL SID    
Account Name:       -   
Account Domain:     -   
Logon ID:       0x0  Logon 
Type:           3  
Account For Which Logon Failed:     
Security ID:        NULL SID    
Account Name:       *******@*******.com     
Account Domain:       
Failure Information:    
Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.  
Status:         0xC000006D  
Sub Status:     0xC000006A  
Process Information:    
Caller Process ID:  0x0     
Caller Process Name:    -  
Network Information:    
Workstation Name:   -   
Source Network Address: **************  Source Port:        0  
Detailed Authentication Information:    
Logon Process:      NtLmSsp     
Authentication Package: NTLM    
Transited Services: -   
Package Name (NTLM only):   -   
Key Length:     0  
This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.  The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.  The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).  The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.  The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.  The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.  
- Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.  
- Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.  
- Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested. 
Event Xml: http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">             4625     0     0     12544     0     0x8010000000000000          118570               Security     *******                S-1-0-0     -     -     0x0     S-1-0-0     *******@*******.com               0xc000006d     %%2313     0xc000006a     3     NtLmSsp      NTLM     -     -     -     0     0x0     -     192.168.11.1     0
```

Any suggestions?

Regards

Comment: Is your machine used to RDP up to date in all respects?  I have RDP'd to a Windows 11 Insider machine from Windows 10 and another Windows 11 Insider machine with no issue.

Comment: The computer doesn't recognize the account that is trying to log on. Has it worked in the past? Is it working on a different, similar computer? Give the details of how you're logging in using RDP or SMB. Edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Well, W11 is up to date but I'm not an insider.
On this W11 only local accounts can login by RDP or SMB.
My account works on all W10 computers, but has never worked on this W11.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like switching the account to local then back to Microsoft fixes the problem.
Anyway bad Microsoft...

Comment: Wow, this actually worked! Thanks for the idea! I recently changed MS account password, and only "switching to local then MS account" worked.